# How to get all request from API with rate limiting using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get all request of API with rate limit of 100 request per minute. This API request is in json format. I used `import urllib`, `import requests` and `import json` and `from time import sleep`. My code below returns the same data

```
import urllib
import requests
import json
import urllib.request as urllib2

from time import sleep

data = []

#resp
for i in range(4):
    url = "https://api.leadfeed.com/accounts/*?start_date=2018-01-01&end_date=2020-06-01"
    header = {"Authorization": 'Bearer GnHbmjtUEQDXCFOlwKAyy9hJedZtDg'}
    resp = requests.get(url, headers = header)
    #print(i)
    data.append(resp.text)
    sleep(60)
print(data)
```

It returns 4 the same json data as shown below:

```
[
    "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"b50b0cf4-06f1-11ea_p6q3nDbB2C4m9KjK9gndy\",\"type\.....}"
    "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"b50b0cf4-06f1-11ea_p6q3nDbB2C4m9KjK9gndy\",\"type\.....}"
    "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"b50b0cf4-06f1-11ea_p6q3nDbB2C4m9KjK9gndy\",\"type\.....}"
    "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"b50b0cf4-06f1-11ea_p6q3nDbB2C4m9KjK9gndy\",\"type\.....}"
]
```

I don't know the length of the json that why i used `range(4)` to return 4 json data.
How can i get data from API with rate limit request?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Your parameters and headers are constant. You're essentially sending the exact same request to the API all 4 times. No wonder you're getting the exact response. What is your expected output?

Comment: @komatiraju032 my question is how can i get request from API which has 100 requests per minute. The API has a lot of data but can only return 100 when called and after 60 secs, when called other data will be returned. So how can i consistently return data after 60 secs

Comment: use infinite loop with `time.sleep()`

Comment: @PrateekDewan my expected output should be different data in json

Comment: How can i use infinite loop with `time.sleep()`

Comment: `keep_going = True; while keep_going:...`